# How can you apply concat(...) in a value-of directive in case of multiple nodes?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I am outputting the `name` node of each `property` node in a `;` delimited string as following:

```
<xsl:value-of select="properties/property/name" separator=";" />
```

I want to alter this such that each element is prefixed with `_`. An example output should be:

```
_alpha;_beta;_gamma
```

I tried the following:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('_', properties/property/name)" separator=";" />
```

I want to use this to create an output node containing that string:

```
<my_node>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('_', properties/property/name)" separator=";" />
</my_node>
```

This gives an error when there are multiple properties:

```
XPTY0004: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed
          as the second argument of fn:concat() (<name>, <name>)
```

Is there a way to get this working in XSLT 2.0/3.0?

I could resort to the XSLT 1.0 `for-each` solution as given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/57856287/12042211 (in which we are manually adding the separator), but I am wondering if something elegant in XSLT 2.0/3.0 is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 3.0 I would tend to write this as

```
<xsl:value-of select="properties/property ! ('_' || name)" separator=";" />
```

and perhaps use `string-join()` instead of `xsl:value-of`. You haven't shown the context, but try to use `xsl:value-of` only when you really want a text node, not when you just want a string.

Comment: Thank you. I am indeed interested in just a string here. I updated my question to reflect this. How should I apply a `string-join()` here? Isn't that applied into a `value-of` as well?

Comment: Once you've got the string (using `string-join()`) you can put it into a text node using `xsl:value-of`, or into an attribute using `xsl:attribute` (or an AVT), or into a variable using `xsl:variable`, or return it from a function using `xsl:sequence`, etc. What I'm saying is, only use `xsl:value-of` if you actually want a text node.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it makes sense now!

Comment: I decided to accept this as the answer, as it made me look into XSLT 3.0 features (http://dh.obdurodon.org/xslt3.xhtml). The introduction of the bang and arrow operators makes things more readable (in my opinion, of course). Also, text expansion is quite nice (`{name}` instead of `<xsl:value-of select="name"/>`), although I believe that cannot be applied here.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes. XSLT 2.0 allows you to write expressions like this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="properties/property/concat('_', name)" separator=";" />
```

So, for each `property` it selects the concatenation of "_" with the `name` element.

Such syntax is not valid in XSLT 1.0 though.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated, that works as expected.